# Getting the size of an layout in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I have the following layout defined:

```
<LinearLayout>
  <TextView />
  <RelativeLayout>
     <TextView>
     <Button>
     <Button>
  </RelativeLayout>
<LinearLayout>
```

now i want to get the height of the RelativeLayout (i want to specify the height of its children programatically):

```
View rel = findViewById(R.id.RelativeLayout01);
int width = rel.getWidth();
int height = rel.getHeight();
```

but the `size returned is 0`. How do I get the size of the RelativeLayout (it's mostly pseudocode above, but both layout have a height/width of "fill_parent" in the xml)

Answer (score 4):

> How do I get the size of the RelativeLayout

Your code is probably OK, but the timing is wrong. You are perhaps executing that code in `onCreate()`, which is too early, as the widgets have not been laid out on the screen yet.

The official answer is for you to extend `RelativeLayout` (or, perhaps, `ViewGroup`) and [implement your own layout rules](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/how-android-draws.html), using `measure()` and `layout()`.